# Can't check if any item inside an array is also in another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I've created a dataframe `c` and array `b`. I've successfully checked that if any of number in the first column of `c` is also in `b`.

```
a = np.array([
                [2.,1.,1.],
                [3.,4.,1.],
                [5.,6.,1.],
                [7.,8.,1.]])

c = pd.DataFrame(data=a,
                 dtype = 'float64')


b = np.array(([1, 10, 5, 2]), dtype = 'float64')

for i in range(len(c)):
    if c.iloc[i,0] in b:
        print ("Great")
    else:
        print ('sad')
```

output:

```
Great
sad
Great
sad
```

However, the following doesn't work when checking if any of the item in b is in c dataframe. Why is that?

```
for i in range(len(b)):
    if b[i,0] in c:
        print ('hola')
    else:
        print ('False')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think better is avoid loops, because slow. So for check columns by array use [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html):

```
mask1 = c[0].isin(b)
print (mask1 )
0     True
1    False
2     True
3    False
Name: 0, dtype: bool

d1 = np.where(mask1, 'Great', 'sad')
print (d1)
['Great' 'sad' 'Great' 'sad']
```

And for check all values use [`DataFrame.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html) with [`any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) for check if at least one `True` per row in `boolean DataFrame`:

```
mask2 = c.isin(b).any(axis=1)
print (mask2)
0    True
1    True
2    True
3    True
dtype: bool

e1 = np.where(mask2, 'hola', 'False')
print (e1)
['hola' 'hola' 'hola' 'hola']
```

Detail:

```
print (c.isin(b))
       0      1     2
0   True   True  True
1  False  False  True
2   True  False  True
3  False  False  True
```

If want check `b` in `c` use [`numpy.in1d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.in1d.html) with flatening values of DataFrame to `1d array` by [`numpy.ravel`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html):

```
mask3 = np.in1d(b, c.values.ravel())
print (mask3)
[ True False  True  True]
```

Comment: But how do you check using the vice-versa logic, i.e. if "b" is in any of the "c"?

Comment: Thanks! Super useful. Any chance of putting it into an IF/Else statement? I'm trying to update values in a np.zeros according to the outcome of this...

Comment: Not sure if understand. Can you explain more? Because in `numpy/pandas` is for `if-else` used `numpy.where`, but not sure what you need ;)

Comment: Basically I have a master list c (dataframe) with customer ID and another subset list b (float64) also containing the customer ID. I want to create a new column or a separate table where if customer is in both list a and b then it updates with a 1 otherwise 0.

Comment: Then need `c['flag'] = c['id'].isin(b).astype(int)` ? If need check column `id` with array `b`.

Comment: If need intersection `c['flag'] = c['id'].isin(set(c['id']) & set(list(b)).astype(int)` should working.